# Select the desired port

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to set a specific port (Ethernet) for publishing topics. I have 2 Ethernet ports, I want only one port to publish topics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311550/select-the-desired-port./) by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-12-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-27**:
@D0l0RES: please clarify why #q311530 is not a duplicate of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a networking question more than it is a ROS question. The answer is it depends on your computer's network configuration.

ROS publishes data to the whole of the network it's connected to, so if both of the ethernet ports on your computer connect to different parts of the same network then messages could be published over both ports. However if your computer is connected to two different networks then you control which one ROS connects to using the ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME environment variables as [described here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME).

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on 2018-12-27**:
what if I have a need to publish data to different networks? it probably won't work like a belt one? or do you need to create several local areas in the global area and set network settings in them?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-27**:
As far as I know ROS is only designed to work across a single network. There may be a solution with a VPN.

**Comment by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on 2018-12-27**:
I'm on this subject wrote the [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/311530/posting-messages-to-different-network-interfaces/)